# What is an unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException'

Tags: c++

When I compile this, it is giving me this message:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Unknown Module.

Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

Can anyone explain what this means? I am pretty sure the code is right. Thanks.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class List;
class Iterator;

class Node
{
public:
/*
    Constructs a node with a given data balue.
    @param s the data to store in this node
    **/
Node(string s);
private:
string data;
Node* previous;
Node* next;
friend class List;
friend class Iterator;

};

class List 
{
public:
/** 
    Constructs an empty list.
    **/
List();
/** 
    Appends an elemetn to the list.
    @param data the value to append
    **/
void push_back(string data);
/**
    Inserts an elemtn into the list.
    @param iter the postion before which to insert
    @param s the value to append
    **/
void insert(Iterator iter, string s);
/**
    Removes an elemtn from the list.
    @param iter the postion to remove
    @param return an iterator pointing to the elemtn after the erased elemtn
    **/
Iterator erase(Iterator iter);
/**
    Gets the beginning position of the list.
    @return an ietartor pointing to the beginning of the list
    **/
Iterator begin();
/**
    Gets the past-the-end position of the list.
    @return an iterator pointing past the end of thel ist
    **/
Iterator end();

private:
Node* first;
Node* last;
friend class Iterator;
};

class Iterator
{
public:
/**
    Constructs an iterator that does not point into any list.
    **/
Iterator();
/**
    Looks up the value at a position.
    @return the value of the node to which the iterator pionts
    **/
string get() const;
/**
    Advances the iterator to the next node.
    **/
void next();
/**
    Moves the iterator to the previous node.
    **/
void previous();
/**
    Compares two iterators.
    @param b the iterator to compare with this iterator
    @return true if this iterator and b are equal
    **/
bool equals(Iterator b) const;
private:
Node* position;
List* container;
friend class List;
};

Node::Node(string s)
{
data = s;
previous= NULL;
next = NULL;
}

List::List()
{
first = NULL;
last = NULL;
}

void List::push_back(string data)
{
Node* new_node = new Node(data);
if (last == NULL) // List is empty
{
    first = new_node;
    last = new_node;

}
else 
{
    new_node->previous = last;
    last->next = new_node;
    last = new_node;
}
 }

void List::insert(Iterator iter, string s)
{
if (iter.position == NULL)
{
    push_back(s);
    return;
}

Node* after = iter.position;
Node* before = after->previous;
Node* new_node = new Node(s);
new_node->previous = before;
new_node->next = after;
after->previous = new_node;
if (before == NULL) // INSERT AT BEGINNING
    first = new_node;
else 
    before->next = new_node;
}

Iterator List::erase(Iterator iter)
{
assert(iter.position != NULL);
Node* remove = iter.position;
Node* before = remove->previous;
Node* after = remove->next;
if (remove == last)
    last = before;
else
    after->previous = before;
delete remove;
Iterator r;
r.position = after;
r.container = this;
return r;
}

Iterator List::begin()
{
Iterator iter; 
    iter.position = first;
iter.position = first;
iter.container = this;
return iter;
}

Iterator List::end()
{
Iterator iter;
iter.position = NULL;
iter.container = this;
return iter;
}

Iterator::Iterator()
{
position = NULL;
container = NULL;
}

string Iterator::get() const
{
assert(position != NULL);
return position->data;
}

void Iterator::next()
{
assert(position != NULL);
position = position->next;
}

void Iterator::previous()
{
assert(position != container->first);
if (position == NULL)
    position = container->last;
else 
    position = position->previous;

}

bool Iterator::equals(Iterator b) const
{
return position == b.position;
}


int main()
{
List staff;

staff.push_back("Tom");
staff.push_back("Dick");
staff.push_back("Harry");
staff.push_back("Juliet");

// Add a value in fourth place

Iterator pos;
pos = staff.begin();
pos.next();
pos.next();
pos.next();

staff.insert(pos, "Romeo");

// Remove the staff in the 2nd place.

pos = staff.begin();
pos.next();

staff.erase(pos);

//Print all values

for (pos = staff.begin(); !pos.equals(staff.end()); pos.next())
    cout << pos.get() << "\n";


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown? Does you get a stack trace?

Comment: when you compile it, are you sure? or when you run it?

Comment: It's when I run it. Its a runtime error.It's a clr empty project using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. call stack location is ntdll.dll!77a65cd4()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this bit in the erase function:

```
 if (remove == first)
    first = after;
  else
    before->next = after;
```